# Random access for hash table

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have an SBCL hash table where the hash keys are symbols. If the hash table was made with `eq`, will calling `gethash` give random access to the elements? I know these details are implementation specific, but so far I haven't been able to find a clear answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume (also from the discussion in the comments) that by "give random access" you mean that the distribution of elements in the hash-table will be random and hence it will have O(1) access performance. The answer is yes, it will be. There are some degraded cases like this one ([Why does `sxhash` return a constant for all structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126507/why-does-sxhash-return-a-constant-for-all-structs)) when the distribution becomes skewed, but this is definitely not it. For `eq` comparisons the implementations will use the address of an object for hashing. In the case of SBCL, here's the actual code:

```
(defun eq-hash (key)
  (declare (values hash (member t nil)))
  ;; I think it would be ok to pick off SYMBOL here and use its hash slot
  ;; as far as semantics are concerned, but EQ-hash is supposed to be
  ;; the lightest-weight in terms of speed, so I'm letting everything use
  ;; address-based hashing, unlike the other standard hash-table hash functions
  ;; which try use the hash slot of certain objects.
  (values (pointer-hash key)
          (sb-vm:is-lisp-pointer (get-lisp-obj-address key))))
```

However, you can also opt to use an `eql` hash-table (which I'd recommend: using `eq` should be reserved only for those who know what they are doing :) ). For this case, SBCL has a special function to hash symbols: `symbol-hash`. I assume, other implementation also do something similar, for symbol is, probably, the most frequent type of hash-table keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables, by design, give O(1) access and update of their elements. It's not implementation specific.

Since hashing works differently than comparing hash tables in standard CL is limited to `eq`, `eql` (default), `equal`, and `equalp`. In reality this only means the hash value for two values considered by one of these to be true will have the same hash value. SBCL lets you define hash functions but that is not portable.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on the second half of your statement? I think that's where my confusion lies. Specifically, can you address "In reality this only means the hash value for two values considered by one of these to be true will have the same hash value"?

Comment: @myselfesteem you provice `:test` when you create the hash table. That only tells the hash table what hashing function to use such that `"test"` and `"test"` only get the same value if `:test` is `equal`, but for `eq` they might have different hash values if they are not pointer equal. Interned symbols, as in `'test`, are always pointer equal and thus `eq` works fine. You really should edit your question with some concrete code as I'm shooting in the dark here.

Comment: The spec doesn't say anything about the performance of hash tables.  It could be O(n), or even worse!  Of course it is not in any competent implementation, but it is not safe to say that it is O(1).

Comment: @tft That would be true even if the spec included wording that required O(1) amortized behavior. An incompetent implementation would ignore, overlook or misunderstand that wording.

Comment: @Kaz: then that implementation would be non-confirming: not mandating it in the spec moves it from a conformance question to a quality-of-implementation question, which is a very different thing.  However it *should* be up to the implementation: an implementation which had, say O(log(n)) performance might easily be preferable to one that had O(n) if the constant is small enough or in other cases.  I just don't think the answer should state it is O(1) when it may not be.

Comment: @tfb Spec doesn't but Wikipedia and all other books will tell you that hash tables are O(1) average search, insert, and delete. This is not a feature of CL but the propeties of hash tables in general. I guess you can implement CL as a linked list without using a hash table at all since it doesn't say, but it won't be popular and it isn't really a hash table. It's as if you implemented vectors with linked lists as well. Can be done, but it isn't vectors.

Comment: @Sylwester: unfortunately that doesn't make your answer correct (and it's not even the case that performance usually is O(1): it's generally something like O(1 + n/k)).  Never mind though.

Comment: Well, alright. So, we are at the same place as before. Does any one know if SBCL hash tables allow for O(1) lookups for symbol keys using `eq`?