# Common Lisp SXHASH and nested lists

Tags: common-lisp, hash-function

The [standard](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sxhash.htm) says that
`(equal x y) implies (= (sxhash x) (sxhash y))`. Let us check it:

```
(defun sxhash-test ()
  (let ((obj1 (list 1 2 (list 1 1)))
        (obj2 (list 1 2 (list 1 2))))
    (format t "are objects equal?: ~a~%" (equal obj1 obj2)) ;; => NIL
    (format t "are their hashes equal?: ~a~%"(= (sxhash obj1) (sxhash obj2))))) ;; => T
```

The function `equal` works as expected but `sxhash` doesn't. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong? I use SBCL 2.1.9.

Thank you.

Comment: Basic logic: `x implies y` doesn't mean that `not x implies not y`.

Comment: There are many more possible lists than hash values. So collisions are possible.

Comment: Does `sxhash` traverse the tree to create the hash? It doesn't seem so. `(list 1 2 3)` and `(list 1 2 4)` create different hashes.

Answer (score 1):

`sxhash` has to satisfy four requirements:

1. objects which are `equal` (and hence objects which are `eql`, `eq`, but not necessarily `equalp` will have the same `sxhash` value;
2. the `sxhash` value of an object must not change during the life of single image unless the object is changed in such a way as to not make it `equal` to a copy of it before the change;
3. objects of various types which have a well-defined notion of similarity between images then their `sxhash` value must be the same in each image.
4. computation of `sxhash` must always terminate.

(There is another vague requirement of 'being a good hash code').

(1) means that two objects which are not `equal` may have the same code but may not, but two objects which *are* `equal` *must* have the same value.  A terrible but possible implementation of `sxhash` would be:

```
(defun sxhash/terrible (it)
  (declare (ignore it))
  0)
```

This fails the 'being a good hash code' test, but that's not something that can really be enforced.

What you are seeing is that two objects which are not `equal` do have the same `sxhash` value: that's fine.

Indeed, (1) together with (4) mean that if an implementation is going to compute `sxhash` on conses in such a way that it walks the graph, then it has to be pretty careful about that: it either needs an occurs check or it needs to only go so deep.

However it is quite possible that `sxhash` does descend into cons trees.  As an example here is [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/) doing just that:

```
> (sxhash '(1 2 3))
11890816076270616

> (sxhash '(1 2 3 (4)))
369102953153702944

> (sxhash '(1 2 3 (4)))
740958182301008344

> (sxhash '(1 2 3 (5)))
740958455027237144

> (sxhash '(1 2 3 (5 6)))
741326672350173760

> (sxhash '(1 2 3 (5 (6))))
925006242171775434
```

Equally it is quite plausible that `sxhash` treats all instances of a given structure class (or of a given instance of `standard-class`) as having the same value, because the address of such an object is not constant and there's no obvious place to store the hash code without burning memory.  But that's in no way a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this effect is observed is that two things are required for the values to be `equal`:

1. The two values are the same, meaning that have the same hash.
2. The two values have the same address

The two lists tested have the same hash, because sxhash doesn't follow nesting. In fact, two structures will always have the same hash.

```
 (sxhash (list 1 2 3)); => 3971322300187561939
 (sxhash (list 1 2 3)); => 3971322300187561939 (so, repeatable)
 (sxhash (list 1 2 3 (list 4))) ; => 3180777146619076709
 (sxhash (list 1 2 3 (list 5))) ; => 3180777146619076709 (ok ...)
```

[Why does `sxhash` return a constant for all structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126507/why-does-sxhash-return-a-constant-for-all-structs)

As for equal addresses, if I create two values like `'a` they in fact turn out to be one item with one address, and is only stored on the first time that it is seen. Whereas `(list 1 2 (list 1 1))` and `(list 1 2 (list 1 2))` are different things and are stored at separate addresses.

```
(sb-kernel:get-lisp-obj-address 'a) ; => 68772678703
(sb-kernel:get-lisp-obj-address 'a) ; => 68772678703 (same...)
(sb-kernel:get-lisp-obj-address (list 1 2 3 (list 4))) ; => 68772925863
(sb-kernel:get-lisp-obj-address (list 1 2 3 (list 5))) ; => 68772805335
```

Testing these two lists for equality pass using sxhash, but fail with different addresses.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `sxhash` may very well walk into lists.  The structure thing is also implementation dependent.